# CSS half arch around full circle

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a half arch around a full circle like below. How would I create this in css? So far I have only created the circle but no idea how to do the arch.

[image: Arch Circle]

```css
.circle {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #BDBDBD;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">1</div>
```

Comment: You can set the color to transparent for some sides, and then rotate the result 45°. Or use SVG.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `:after` pseudo-element to create half circle. You also need to use `bottom-right` and `top-right` border-radius.

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #BDBDBD;
  color: white;
}

.circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  width: 55px;
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  transform: translate(15px, -15px);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">1</div>
```

Comment: Ah great! So this is.

Comment: Quick question if I want to reduce the width of the arch, what formula do you apply to height: calc(100% + 10px) and transform: translate(15px, -15px) ?

Comment: Correct! So how do you what to set translate and height too based on the border width?

Comment: @Ka Tech Take a look at this fiddle, formula is in js box. https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2000/

Answer (score 1):

This is based on jcaron's comment on the question. I wrapped the circle with an outer-circle div to create the "white space between greys" area.

Nenad Vracar's answer however seems to be much cleaner.

```css
.outer-circle {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1x 1px 0 0;
  border-color: #BDBDBD #BDBDBD transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.circle {
  background: #BDBDBD;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
  <div class="circle">
    1
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes use `pseudo selector`, but your `parent` background needs to be `white` or any other color that merge with pseudo selector i.e. the center part between circle and half arch or do that using canvas.

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 70px solid transparent;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 70px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -2;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: -15px;
  top: -20px;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 60px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -10px;
  left: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
```